# Disparar e-mail automatico em determinado horário com java

Tags: java, thread

Meu sistema tem a parte de consultas odontológicas e preciso enviar e-mail para o cliente, caso a sua consulta seja naquele dia.

Por exemplo:
Rodar um disparador automático de e-mail sempre a meia noite em todos os dias. Esse disparador de e-mail vai verificar se possui consultas naquele dia e se tiver, vai enviar o e-mail.

Como faço para rodar essa verificação com java?

Comment: Sua dúvida é para fazer a verificação ou para agendar a execução de um código? No primeiro caso, é preciso conhecer seu modelo de dados. No segundo, varia de sistema operacional, vc precisa informar.

Comment: Quero agendar a execução da verificação de consultas. Meia noite rodar um método que verifica se há consultas naquele dia.

Comment: Então qual sistema operacional??

Comment: É Windows mesmo :D

Comment: Existem duas formas de fazer agendamentos, "jobs", em aplicações java, existe um post neste [link](http://blog.alura.com.br/agendando-tarefas-com-scheduled-do-spring/) que certamente vai te nortear.

Comment: Uma outra opção seria utilizar o EJB para fazer o agendamento no próprio java, no mesmo método você poderia fazer a verificação que você quisesse. http://blog.caelum.com.br/agendando-tarefas-com-o-timerservice-do-ejb-3-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem frameworks de agendamento de tarefas, no entanto para apenas executar um script diariamente você pode usar soluções bem mais simples. Os sistemas operacionais possuem um agendador de tarefas: no linux tem o `cron`, no windows tem o `Agendador de Tarefas` (nome menos criativo, diga-se de passagem).

Basicamente você cria um programa em java que ao ser executado envia os emails com as consultas, sem se preocupar com o horário. Para agendar, você cria um script como esse:

```
@echo off
REM run the program
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\User1    \Documents\project\emailConsulta.jar"
```

Então, basta criar uma tarefa no Agendador de Tarefas do Windows, acessado com Win+R > digite "Taskschd.msc" > Enter. Lá você controla em quais dias da semana ele vai ser executado, em qual horário, entre outras opções.